# Getting a null error while hitting Update API for the field I dont need to change AND how to pass multiple REQUEST BODY?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm getting field DOB cant be null while hitting update API, but I don't want to update DOB so not passing it in payload on Postman. Still getting this error. DOB field is set to NOT NULL in database, but its a update API.

AND

I am sending 2 @RequestBody in Controller Function, how can I send  in single?

ERROR

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'dob' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1350) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na].............
```

**Service Code**
I have two two different tables and model class, **orgPatient and PatientContact**, and I have to update in both tables accordingly.

```
public String updateColumn(String PatientId, OrgPatient orgPatient,PatientContact patientContact) {

            Patient existPatient = PatientRepository.findByPatientId(PatientId);
        
        if (existPatient != null) {
         

            OrgPatient updatedUser = orgPatientRepository.findByOrgPatientId(PatientId);
    PatientContact updatedContactUser = patientContactRepository.findByPatientId(PatientId);
          

            if (patientOrgId != null) {
                updatedUser.setFirstName(orgPatient.getFirstName());
                updatedUser.setMiddleName(orgPatient.getMiddleName());
                updatedUser.setLastName(orgPatient.getLastName());
                updatedUser.setDob(orgPatient.getDob());
                updatedUser.setGender(orgPatient.getGender());
         

                updatedContactUser.setContactNumberType(patientContact.getContactNumberType());
                updatedContactUser.setContactNumer(patientContact.getContactNumer());
                updatedContactUser.setContactAreaCode(patientContact.getContactAreaCode());

                orgPatientRepository.save(updatedUser);
                patientContactRepository.save(updatedContactUser);
                return "updated";
            } 
        }
```

Controller Class

```
@PutMapping(value="/update/{PatientId}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateOrg(@PathVariable String PatientId,
                                            @RequestBody OrgPatient orgPatient,
                                            @RequestBody PatientContact patientContact) {

        String ans=  updateOrgPatientService.updateOrgColumn(PatientId,orgPatient,patientContact);
     
       return ResponseEntity.ok(ans);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't map the field if its null.

```
if (orgPatient.getDob() != null) updatedUser.setDob(orgPatient.getDob());
```

Your other option is to make the Dob field required and return a 400 response if its null.